# Use multiple xlink:href references inside the same tag, ideally under own, custom names

Tags: xml, xsd, href, xlink

So I can have (pardon me for the bad schema structure of this example but it's only to make a point) the following XML:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <person id="W1" xsi:type="woman" eyes="blue"/>
  <person id="M1" xsi:type="man" eyes="brown"/>
  <person xsi:type="child">
        <parent ancestor="mother" xlink:href="W1"/>
        <parent ancestor="father" xlink:href="M1"/>
  </person>
</xml>
```

but could I make it much more dense?

In particular to collapse reference links into attributes of the person directly?

Something like having two hrefs (here `hrefM` and `hrefF` respectively as can't have multiple attributes of same name…):

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <person id="W1" xsi:type="woman" eyes="blue"/>
  <person id="M1" xsi:type="man" eyes="brown"/>
  <person xsi:type="child" xlink:hrefM="W1" xlink:hrefF="M1"/>
</xml>
```

?

I know I can just drop whole xlink idea and use my own attribute names (`uid` and `refM`, `refF`):

```
<xml>
  <person uid="W1" xsi:type="woman" eyes="blue"/>
  <person uid="M1" xsi:type="man" eyes="brown"/>
  <person xsi:type="child" refM="W1" refF="M1"/>
</xml>
```

but then I am making my own, lame "standard".

I am wondering if XLink could be still used but with schema/structure adapted to cater for (1) **custom names** (`uid`, `refF`, `refM`) and (2) **multiple** reference attributes inside same tag?

Answer (score 0):

> I am wondering if XLink could be still used but with schema/structure adapted to cater for (1) custom names (uid, refF, refM) and (2) multiple reference attributes inside same tag?

What you're asking for is not possible. The [Xlink standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink) defines all of its attributes, like `href`, `type`, `role` etc. as global attributes. If you use any attribute not part of the standard then you lose the benefit of using a common W3C standard that other consuming applications would already know. The nature of XML requires that any XML schema that defines attribute names, the names must be known in advance - basically, it does not allow variadic attribute names.

I think you should reconsider the first example XML you provided:

```
<xml xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <person id="W1" xsi:type="woman" eyes="blue"/>
  <person id="M1" xsi:type="man" eyes="brown"/>
  <person xsi:type="child">
        <parent ancestor="mother" xlink:href="W1"/>
        <parent ancestor="father" xlink:href="M1"/>
  </person>
</xml>
```

There's a section of the [XLink standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/xlink/#extended-link) ('*Extended links*') that basically recommends doing what you've already done here. Their own sample XML is pretty close:

```
  <person
    xlink:href="students/patjones62.xml"
    xlink:label="student62"
    xlink:role="http://www.example.com/linkprops/student"
    xlink:title="Pat Jones" />

  <person
    xlink:href="profs/jaysmith7.xml"
    xlink:label="prof7"
    xlink:role="http://www.example.com/linkprops/professor"
    xlink:title="Dr. Jay Smith" />
```